# Project reference won't detect my class

Tags: c#, .net, class-library

I'm currently trying to set up a project, but I encountered an issue I didn't have before.

Even though I've added the reference of my class library to another class library, it can't find my `Events.cs` class.

I've tried changing the framework on all projects to 3.5, 4, 4.5.2. Also tried to restart Visual Studio.

This is my project setup:

- Project.App (.NET fw 4.0)
- Project.Domain (.NET fw 4.0)

  - Models

    - Events.cs
- Project.Handlers (.NET fw 4.0)

  - IEventRepository.cs
  - IRepository.cs

In `Project.Handlers` I've put a reference to `Project.Domain`.

Here is the code of my `Event.cs`:

```
namespace Project.Domain.Models
{
    class Event
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Next my code of my `IRepository.cs`:

```
namespace Project.Handlers
{
    internal interface IRepository<T> where T: class 
    {
        T Get();
    }
}
```

And last is my code of the `IEventRepository.cs`:

```
using Project.Domain;
namespace Project.Handlers
{
    class IEventRepository : IRepository<Event>
    {
        public Event Get()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Accessibility Levels (c#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx): "Top-level types, which are not nested in other types, can only have internal or public accessibility. The default accessibility for these types is internal."

Comment: Also you might want to use `Project.Domain.Models` if your Event class is really in this namespace

Answer (score 3):

No accessmodifier for your Event class will make it internal by default. Thats why you wont be able to access it from another project.

Make it

```
public class Event {
///
}
```

to be able to access it from another project.

Comment: This solves it, I thought when you make a new class, the default would be public. Guess it's not :)